# diff() excluding the first row of each group

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the difference between the consecutive values in a data frame (which I have already grouped). When I used the below code, all the first-row "Value" fields are changing to NAN's which I will be needing. I want to exclude the first row from the diff operation. Can somebody help me, please?

```
SNo  Var %    Value
1000    0    1.2
1000    1    2.2
1000    2    3.2
1000    3    4.2
1000    4    5.2
1000    4    6.2
1000    5    7.2
1000    5    8.2
1001    0    0.5
1001    1    1.5
1001    2    2.5
1001    2    3.5
```

```
x['value_diff'] = x.groupby('SNo').value.diff()
```

```
SNo  Var %    Value
1000    0    NAN
1000    1    1
1000    2    1
1000    3    1
1000    4    1
1000    4    1
1000    5    1
1000    5    1
1001    0    NAN
1001    1    1
1001    2    1
1001    2    1
```

Comment: adding dropna ?

Comment: `df.groupby('SNo').Value.diff().fillna(df.Value)` ?

Comment: @anky_91 Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the first-row "Value" fields are changing to NAN's which I will be needing.

As mentioned in the comments, you need:

```
df.groupby('SNo').Value.diff().fillna(df.Value)
```

This will fill the `NaN` in the same index from `Value` column

---

```
0     1.2
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     1.0
7     1.0
8     0.5
9     1.0
10    1.0
11    1.0
```